# Ajax Response Finding HTML Fragments Using Find

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, filter, find

I was doing some test with JQuery find , I have an html response coming from an AJAX request, so initially the result would be this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>   
      <div id="dashboard">
        <div id="dash2">
            <h1>Hi</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In My Ajax Success code is this..

```
success : function(response,status) {                       
    console.log( $(response).find('#dashboard').html() );
}
```

Upon printing it on the console that gives me an `undefined`.

However when I modify the response page(I created a nesting div) to this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
        <div id="div1">
            <div id="dashboard">
                <div id="dash2">
                    <h1>Hi</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The line from my Ajax Success code returned  `console.log( $(response).find('#dashboard').html() );` returned the

```
<div id="dash2">
    <h1>Hi</h1>
</div>
```

My Question, How come on the first HTML  when doing the `console.log( $(response).find('#dashboard').html() );` it gave me an undefined, however on the second HTML(the one nested in the div) gave me the the contents of `#dashboard`(which the one I am expecting to get.

Comment: use `filter()` for top level of `body`

Comment: Why should I use filter() for top level of body?

Comment: because `$()` will strip out html, head and body tags leaving your first `div` at root level. This is so don't end up with 2 body's, head's etc which would be invalid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know it is a browser dependent behavior to which tags to drop as a measure of sanitation, e.g. `<head/>`.

The reason for not finding `#dashboard` while executing

```
$(response).find('#dashboard')
```

is most probably because `#dashboard` has become the root element after the sanitation, and `.find()` matches against the descendant elements not on the root itself.

I normally to avoid this problem do this over an empty `<div>`.

```
$("<div/>").html(response).find('#dashboard')
```

Comment: Thanks! helped me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23885909/jquery-ajax-get-result-doesnt-find-class/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery strips everything except the contents of the body, so `#dashboard` is at the top level so `find` would actually be searching for descendants of `#dashboard`. Since `#dashboard` is at the top level you can use filter to select it out of the other top level nodes.

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/SqL9Q/

Comment: If I use filter and  the div that I am getting tags has script elements(eg event handlers), would it still be able to execute?