# jquery ajax $.get result doesn't find class

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I got stuck on a seemingly simple problem.

I want to fetch the resulting HTML from a ajax request and look whether or not a specific element has a specific class and take the HTML of another element of the response and use it to replace something etc...

```
$(function() {
    $('.js-nav').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $url = $this.attr('href');

        $.get($url.url, function(response) {
                var $response = $(response);

                var $body = $response.find('.js-wrapper').html();
                var _isLight = $response.find('.js-wrapper').hasClass('body-light');

                console.log($body);
                console.log(_isLight);

                History.pushState({ state:$url }, $title, $url);
        });
    });
});
```

The console returns this:

```
undefined
false
```

Now the `.js-wrapper` element is not in the header but on a `div` that is inside the body.

The response HTML *(console.logged out after it was retrieved with $.get)* looks as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]><html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js" lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>
        some title ...
    </title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- some header stuff like css files and scripts(the ones that HAVE to be in the header) -->

</head>
<body>



    <div class="js-wrapper wrapper body-light">
        <header class="js-header header">
            <!-- some content divs and whatnot -->

            <nav class="header-nav">
                <ul class="js-header-nav-list header-nav-list">

                        <li class="header-nav-item">
                            <!-- a couple nav li -->
                        </li>

                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

                <div class="content">
                    <!-- Content -->
                </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <section class="footer-newsletter">

                    <!-- footer sections... -->

            </section>
        </footer>
    </div>


    <!-- Some scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

*(I included the historyJS call just in case it could have something to do with it)*

Help is, as always, appreciated.

Comment: post your response html pls

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML?

Comment: console.log response and paste it in here pls.

Comment: Added it into the question

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678500/ajax-response-finding-html-fragments-using-find

Comment: @Dominik you should `console.log($(response))`. I don't think it is what you think it is.

Comment: @David yes well if I was to post the jQuery object like you want then you'll get a lot of stuff no-one needs right now I thought. I did add the pure HTML response in the question.

Comment: @GirishSakhare Please add this as an answer. This fixed my issue!

Comment: use  var $responsehtml = $.parseHTML(response);

Comment: @rjdmello nixe one. I would love to know the performance difference between ```$.parseHTML(response);``` and ```$("<div/>").html(response);```

Comment: parseHTML just parse your response string to html i.e. dom nodes

Comment: Is there a difference to ```$(response)``` then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Girish Sakhare comment and @Alexanders answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678500/ajax-response-finding-html-fragments-using-find) I got the solution:

```
var $response = $("<div/>").html(response);
```

So the function looks like this now:

```
$(function() {
    $('.js-nav').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this);
        var $url = $this.attr('href');

        $.get($url, function(response) {
                var $response = $("<div/>").html(response);

                var $body = $response.find('.js-wrapper').html();
                var _isLight = $response.find('.js-wrapper').hasClass('body-light');

                console.log($body);
                console.log(_isLight);

                History.pushState({ state:$url }, $title, $url);
        });
    });
});
```

So I had to append the response to an empty `div` first.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would first echo out the response and make sure your getting the correct html back.

Then you can confirm you have the html with the specific class.

The .hasClass is exactly what you want, the undefined is probably because you're not getting the html back, to confirm console log it.

use $('Your Div').contents();

To get the html content

Then   $('Where you want to place html Div').append(Your Div);

Comment: I have added more infos to my question. The response is correct and a stripped down version is in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like, you are trying to get a property which should not exist i.e

```
$url.url
```

You $.get code block should look like this

```
   $.get($url, function(response) {
                var $response = $(response);

                var $body = $response.find('.js-wrapper').html();
                var _isLight = $response.find('.js-wrapper').hasClass('body-light');

                console.log($body);
                console.log(_isLight);

                History.pushState({ state:$url }, $title, $url);
        });
```

Comment: yeah weird! This is a bug/typo but it worked anyway... Thanks for the hint. (this did not fix the issue though... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678500/ajax-response-finding-html-fragments-using-find for the sollution)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work in the

```
{ http://jsfiddle.net/Px6tu/ }
```

Please try to console log the response to make sure you are getting what is expected.

Also have a look [Ajax Response Finding HTML Fragments Using Find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678500/ajax-response-finding-html-fragments-using-find)

Comment: the console log is in the answer